# ¿Como hago una actualización masiva y especifica de datos en Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Lo que necesito modificar el campo *reciente* de todos los documentos en la base de datos, pero cada documento posee un valor diferente para ser modificado, por lo que no podría solo modificarlos con *updateMany*.

Voy a ejemplificar el problema con estos to do:

```javascript
db.todos.insertMany([
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "reciente": ObjectId("62c5be1fb06cac1d5c042cde")
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "reciente": ObjectId("62c5be1fb06cac1d5c042cde")
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
    "reciente": ObjectId("62c5be1fb06cac1d5c042cde")
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "eum et est occaecati".
    "reciente": ObjectId("62c5be1fb06cac1d5c042cde")
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "title": "nesciunt quas odio".
    "reciente": ObjectId("62c5be1fb06cac1d5c042cde")
  },
]);
```

Tengo un arreglo con los *_id* de todos los documentos, y un arreglo con el valor a actualizar para cada document:

```javascript
const _ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const valores = [
    ObjectId("62c5be1fb06cac1dac04dddd"),
    ObjectId("62c5be1fb06dac1ad5c02ccq"),
    ObjectId("62c5be1fb061ad1d5c042cdc"),
    ObjectId("62c5be1fb06cac1d5c342zcs"),
    ObjectId("62c5be1fb06cac1d5c042v3q")
];
```

Y por ahora no encuentro una solución que no sea iterar los arreglos y hacer una consulta por cada uno, lo cual no me parece muy eficiente.

¿Existe alguna solución más optima?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para agrupar operaciones relacionadas puede utilizarse `Bulk()`, para este caso, si se tuvieran los objetos indicados, las actualizaciones se harían así:

```js
const bulk = db.todos.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
_ids.forEach((id, index) =>
  bulk
    .find({ id })
    .update({ $set: { reciente: valores[index] } })
)
bulk.execute()
```

De este modo se agruparán y ejecutarán todas las operaciones de actualización.